# sql procedure returns only the last row instead of multiple rows

Tags: sql

I have verified that the procedure does return multiple ro
The problem is that my sql procedure returns only one row, but from asp side I can only get one:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE cphsdbm.tp_Trip_List
@UserID int,
@Trip_Name varchar(50) output
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @Trip_Name = Trip_Name FROM tbl_Trip WHERE UserID=@UserID; 
END
```

My code:

```
do
{
while (rdr2.Read())
{
trip_count++;
Response.Write("Success!");
}
trip_count++;
} while (rdr2.NextResult());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return multiple rows, your stored procedure should return a result set (rather than a single output value), i.e.:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE cphsdbm.tp_Trip_List 
@UserID int
AS 
BEGIN 
     SELECT Trip_Name FROM tbl_Trip WHERE UserID = @UserID;  
END
```

To read:

```
while (rdr2.Read()) 
{ 
   trip_count++; 

   // ... do something with trip name...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The stored procedure you are using should not return even one row. It will only return `Trip_Name` value in `output` variable you are passing to the stored procedure. I don't know the structure of your database or what you need to read from table so I cannot suggest anything further unless you elaborate on your requirement.

Moreover there will not be any `NextResult()` in the reader.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response. I really appreciate your help and quick response. This site is great!!!